# I want to reach to children of a gameobject on OntriggerEnter

Tags: unity-game-engine, triggers

this is the code that I got for Collision.what should I do for Trigger.means that when i trying to use contacts I got nothing!

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
        Collider myCollider = collision.contacts[0].thisCollider;
        // Now do whatever you need with myCollider.
        // (If multiple colliders were involved in the collision, 
        // you can find them all by iterating through the contacts)
    }
```

Comment: does your gameobject have a collider component ? or collision mesh ?

Comment: yes , it has circlecollidar2d on it , certainly parent and its children had circlecollidar and I want to destroy its children as it touches goal.

Comment: If the collider is attached to the children gameobject, the OnCollisionEnter will trigger on the children. So maybe what you could do is do your logic on the children GameObject.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is you want to access the child of collided gameobject.
You can get other children by providing index number of the child GameObject such as 1,2,3, to the [GetChild](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html) function.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    
GameObject child = collision.gameobject.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;

}
```

For Multiple Colliders refer this [thread](https://answers.unity.com/questions/188775/having-more-than-one-collider-in-a-gameobject.html)

Answer (score 0):

Trigger (colliders with `isTrigger` enabled) won't cause an [`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) but only [`OnTriggerEnter(Collider)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html).

See also [Colliders -> Collision Action Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)

=> for triggers you won't get any information about the contact points.

Comment: certainly I want to destroy a GameObject child  as it touches goal with OntriggerEnter